# Is the definition of Critical Section wrong or being misused?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, critical-section

I was wondering what would be the exactly definition of critical section. Lots of content on the internet defines as "A part of the code where two or more process/threads should not access at the same time". But it turns out that people are using this term in situation where multiple Threads, with proper care, could in fact access at the same time. For example in readers-writers problem it's common to say that multiple readers can access the critical section

- "It cannot be executed by more than one process at a time" - Part of the definition by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)
- "When no Writer is active any number of Readers can access the critical area" - [Article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4507.pdf) describing the readers-writers problem.

Comment: Try the literal meaning of “critical section”: the section where it matters or the section where you have to care.

Answer (score 1):

"Critical section," AFAIK, is nomenclature <strike>that pre-dates threads</strike> from a time before multiprocessors and multi-threaded application programs became commonplace. In older operating systems and embedded systems, a critical section was a sequence of instructions that was executed with interrupts disabled.

When we use mutexes in multi-threaded application programs, same as when we wrote "crictical sections" back in the old days, what we're trying to protect never is or was a "section" of code. What we're really trying to protect is *data* that are shared between threads or other concurrent executions.

It's often the case in modern programs that some function running in one thread can lock a mutex and access some data, while a different activation of the same function could be running in some other thread, locking a *different* mutex that protects a *different* shared instance of the same data type.

Comment: Threads predated processes.   Some tiny systems definitely used interrupt lockout for this, but no, general operating systems have had concurrency controls at least since the early 1960s when Dijkstra described semaphores.